# Android Access Point Default Network

Tags: android, access-point

I'm facing a problem when using a [S31 Cat phone](https://www.catphones.com/fr_fr/cat-s31-smartphone.html) with Android 7.1.2. But i'm not sure this problem is related to this phone or simply Android 7
I've tried this on Sony Xperia and others Samsung phones.

I'm currently developping an app that creates an access point with reflection methods (with or without this library :[Wifi Ap Control](https://github.com/mvdan/accesspoint)).
After creating the access Point another device is connecting to the Access Point and initiating TCP Server. My App try to create a Socket to this server.

Here is how i'm creating the Access Point:

```
    WifiConfiguration myConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
    myConfig.SSID = ssid; // SSID name of netwok
    myConfig.preSharedKey = password; // password for network
    myConfig.allowedKeyManagement.set(4); // 4 is for KeyMgmt.WPA2_PSK which is not exposed by android KeyMgmt class
    myConfig.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN); // Set Auth Algorithms to open
    try {
        Method method = mWifiManager.getClass().getMethod("setWifiApEnabled", WifiConfiguration.class, boolean.class);
        return (Boolean) method.invoke(mWifiManager, myConfig, true);  // setting and turing on android wifiap with new configrations
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and Here is how i'm simply creating the Socket :

```
   try {
        socketTcp = new Socket();
        socketTcp.connect(new InetSocketAddress(address, port), SOCKET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        receiveStream = socketTcp.getInputStream();
        sendStream = socketTcp.getOutputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
```

When i'm trying to create and connect the socket, two different things happen : 
When i'm manually starting the Access Point, i get an exceptions when the device is not connected, but that's fine, because I ca connect to it when it's connected to the access point.

```
03-09 09:00:41.336 22049-22081/eu.test.socket W/System.err: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
```

or

```
03-09 09:00:43.342 22049-22081/eu.test.socket W/System.err: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
```

But when i'm doing it with reflection, i'm getting another type of exception. And i cannot connect to the device even if it's actually connected to the access point !

```
03-09 08:55:41.086 21265-21300/eu.test.socket W/System.err: java.net.ConnectException: Network is unreachable
```

I'm starting to guess that when doing this reflecion method, Android can't find default Network methods to bind the socket.

Do you have any idea regarding this problem ?